# External monitor works initially in mirrored mode, but not in Extended mode - Ubuntu Studio 20.04 XFCE

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, xfce, external-monitor

**System:**
Kernel: 5.4.0-65-lowlatency x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0
Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 tk: Gtk 3.24.13 info: xfce4-panel wm: xfwm4
dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)
**Machine:**
Type: Laptop System: Dell product: G5 5590 v: N/A serial: 
Chassis: type: 10 serial: 
Mobo: Dell model: 0CNDTP v: A00 serial:  UEFI: Dell v: 1.14.0
date: 10/20/2020
**CPU:**
Topology: 6-Core model: Intel Core i7-9750H bits: 64 type: MT MCP
arch: Kaby Lake rev: A L2 cache: 12.0 MiB
flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
bogomips: 62399
Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/2600 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800
3: 800 4: 800 5: 800 6: 800 7: 800 8: 800 9: 800 10: 800 11: 800 12: 800
**Graphics:**
Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 630 vendor: Dell driver: i915 v: kernel
bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:3e9b
Device-2: NVIDIA TU106M [GeForce RTX 2060 Mobile] vendor: Dell
driver: nouveau v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.0 chip ID: 10de:1f11
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa
resolution: 1920x1080~144Hz
OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.6
direct render: Yes

xandr output summary:

> eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
> HDMI-1-3 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Upon a reboot (and this is a dual boot setup), if I plug in an external monitor via HDMI, it comes right up in mirror mode. If I then select Extended Mode, all content disappears from it, though I can still see the pointer if I mouse over to that screen. Attempts to return to Mirror Mode leave the external monitor in this odd blank-like look.

There is no such problem if I boot into Windows 10

I cannot find any previous solutions that solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this is a hardware button issue. Have you tried <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to toggle the monitor switching function? When you do, you should see a screen like this:

[image: XFCE Display Layout]

Choose the option that you would like and go from there. I've seen similar issues on Dell Vostro notebooks, so perhaps your G5 will respond just the same.

Hope this helps

Comment: This screen comes up when i plug the monitor in, and the external screen initially shows as mirrored. I never get successfully past that point, though before this never had any such problem with Ubuntu in the last decade.